# How to programmatically hide android some, but not all, view items in an XML output?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I'm trying to program a disc golf scoring app on Eclipse for my android phone. I'd like to set it up for up to 6 players, but mostly 2 people will use it for a game. The data is being stored in a sqlite DB, and I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate the data for holes that have already been scored. here is that code:

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)

    String[] from = new String[]{DiscGolfDbAdapter.KEY_HOLE,
            DiscGolfDbAdapter.KEY_PAR,
            DiscGolfDbAdapter.KEY_TOM_HOLE,
            DiscGolfDbAdapter.KEY_TOM_GAME,
            DiscGolfDbAdapter.KEY_CRAIG_HOLE,
            DiscGolfDbAdapter.KEY_CRAIG_GAME,
            DiscGolfDbAdapter.KEY_TOMS_POSITION,
            DiscGolfDbAdapter.KEY_SKIP_PLAYER
    };

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.schole, R.id.scpar, R.id.scth, R.id.sctg, R.id.scch, R.id.sccg, R.id.sctp,
            R.id.skip};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.hole_info, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

From searching the internet I've found what I think are two posibilities that SHOULD work, but do not.

First I've tried the XML Attribute: android.visibility. It looks like this in the PORTION of the view that I am trying to "test" hide:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android.visibility="GONE">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/scch"
        android:layout_width="45dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/sccg"
        android:layout_width="45dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried it with "GONE", "Gone" and "gone". NONE of them work in the eclipse emulator OR on my actual phone. So, there is no point in trying to parameterize this attribute.

Next I've tried setting the XML attribute for android:layout_height to "0dip". This indeed works in the emulator and on my phone WHEN IT IS HARDCODED.

Then I moved to the next logical step (as I see it), storing a parameter in the DB so that I can "show" or "not show" the item DEPENDING on conditions within the record. So, I've stored a field in the DB with two values "0dip" and "wrap_content". I pass these to the layout as shown in the java above as R.id.skip. I've also added these to the output just to audit that they are really there. Here is that XML:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@+id/skip">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/scch"
        android:layout_width="45dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/sccg"
        android:layout_width="45dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/skip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="315dip"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In the above test, both via the Eclipse emulator and my android phone, the last TextView confirms that the DB contains either "0dip" or "wrap_content", BUT the LinearLayout with:

```
      android:layout_height="@+id/skip">
```

behaves as if it were "0dip" ALL of the TIME. In other words, I cannot PROGRAMMATICALLY" affect the XML attribute for android:layout_height.

If there is a better/more standard way of accomplishing what I am trying to do, please share - BUT BE CLEAR. I am new, so CODE EXAMPLES wwill work best for me.

---

May 29th - It seems to me (based on testing) that you cannot alter layout attributes for the layout specified in this code:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                                                    R.layout.hole_info, 
                                                    notesCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(notes);
```

Anything I try leads to some error ort another. So, I've seen examples of custom list adapters where these attributes are altered, so I'm trying to convert to a custom list adapter.

Answer (score 14):

Why not do it in code?

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I assume by "in code", you mean in java. I would want to interogate values being read from each record. I do not know where to do that. Is it via some option of:

Comment: Sorry - I didn't know tab would add the comment. Is that via fetchAllNotes, startManagingCursor, SimpleCursorAdapter or setListAdapter? If so, how is that done and what is the santax for your suggestion "LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id); ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);" to make that conditionally happen?

Comment: The code I wrote earlier is the general way to programmatically hide a layout. However, I have not quite understood your problem, partly because I do not know the rules of this game. I suppose you have a number of `LinearLayout`s and you want to hide some of them depending on one or more conditions, is that correct? If that so, what are those conditions and when (in code) are you checking for them?

Comment: As an example, I'd like to hide one or more (but not all) of the embedded LinearLayouts show below:

Comment: In the below EMBEDDED LinearLayout, which is one of several in the whole XML Layout, I'd like to hide THIS PIECE if @+id.scch is blank.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML layout code

```
android.visibility="GONE"
```

should be

```
android:visibility="GONE"
```

Change visible of a LinearLayout like Gabriel Neguţ say:

> LinearLayout ll =
>   (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
>   ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

or change height of LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = 0; // or lp.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this guy's solution http://enjoyandroid.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/customizing-simple-cursor-adapter/

Kind of worked for me.